# How can I add drawables to my res folder in intelij IDEA?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I am new to intelij IDEA. I have just discovered that there is no drawables folder in my res folder.
Do the drawables come automatically or you just have to add it by yourself?If so how it is been done?
I will appreciate your response.

Comment: @user370305 thanks for responding i was expecting it to be automatically generated under res but i can only see layout and values.

Answer (score 0):

Just drag and drop the image from the source folder to idea res/drawable package.  I know for a fact it works for PNG image.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio you can press mouse right button on res folder and then go in new section and choose "Image Asset". In it find "Asset Type" press on it and select "Action Bar and Tab Icons" then select your image path, write name for it and that's all. Although if you won't see it just select "Project" isteaad of Android in left Project menu

Answer (score -1):

Right click on *res* folder: *New -> Android resource directory*.

Select resource type: *drawable*, change parameters as you wish, press *OK*.

Ready!

Comment: This will create an xml... i would like to add images at various densities like it works in eclipse.